# Does Add-In startup speed increase with Com Shim?

Tags: vb.net, com, ms-office, add-in, shim

I am a non-professional who has a working Office Add-In written in VB for Visual Studio 10. It has no "written" problems.

I want to speed up the startup of the application because the Add-In seems to cause a 4-5 seconds delay.

I stumbled on this thing called COM SHIM WIZARD. Since this looks like a nightmare for a non-professional to implement, I want to ask:

1) Most sources I found were a little bit old. Is this something still used and usefull ? Some sources behave like it is a must for an Add-In, but it isn't for VS 2010 at least.

2) Will implementing COM SHIM WIZARD speed up my Add-In load if I manage to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that using custom com shim will speed up anything. VSTO provides it's own out of the box, so there is really no reason for custom one.

You may consider profiling your add-in to see what exactly is causing the delays.

May be simply using ngen.exe will solve your loading issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and introducing me to ngen.exe. The downvote - that wasn't me

Comment: No problem. Maybe there are some advantages of custom shim I'm not aware of :)